# Radio Buttons looped in jinja2 only first entry gets selected when there is CSS?

Tags: python, css, flask, jinja2

We want to make different ratings per books borrowed by a user in our library system so there's a loop with a form that only has textarea and a set of radio button. For some reason, when CSS is applied, only in the first entry can the user click the radio button and the CSS works (displays text like "I love it", etc).

The next instances of the div class however, the stars/radio buttons aren't clickable anymore. However, when we completely remove the CSS, we can interact with the other radio buttons just fine. I'm not sure how to resolve it as we need to have CSS for the end project.

HTML

```
{%for transaction in shelfinfos%}
<form action="/account/addreview/{{transaction['book_id']}}" method="POST">
   <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="center">
         <div class="stars">
            <input type="radio" id="five" name="rate" value="5" required>
            <label for="five"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="four" name="rate" value="4">
            <label for="four"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="three" name="rate" value="3">
            <label for="three"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="two" name="rate" value="2">
            <label for="two"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="one" name="rate" value="1">
            <label for="one"></label>
            <span class="result"></span>
         </div>
      </div>
      <textarea id="review" class="text-control"
         name="review" placeholder="Your thoughts..."></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
         data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save
      changes</button>
   </div>
</form>
{%endfor%}
```

CSS

```
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.center .stars{
  text-align: center;
}
.stars {
  align-self: center;
}
.stars input{
  display: none;
}
.stars label{
  float: right;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: lightgrey;
  margin: 0 5px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #bbb;
}
.stars label:before{
  content: '★';
}
.stars input:checked ~ label{
  color: gold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #c60;
}
.stars:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.stars:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label{
  color: gold;
}
.stars input:checked > label:hover,
.stars input:checked > label:hover ~ label{
  color: gold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px goldenrod;
}
.stars input:checked ~ .result:before{
  display: block;
}
.stars #five:checked ~ .result:before{
  content: "I love it ";
}
.stars #four:checked ~ .result:before{
  content: "I like it ";
}
.stars #three:checked ~ .result:before{
  content: "It's good ";
}
.stars #two:checked ~ .result:before{
  content: "I don't like it ";
}
.stars #one:checked ~ .result:before{
  content: "I hate it ";
}
</style>
```

Comment: It appears that the HTML being created has errors - because you have multiple elements with the same id which is not allowed. What do you do on a click - is there a Javascript function involved?

Comment: It's basically a way to rate different books. You click on a radio and it has the rating value, and you submit with a button. No JavaScript involved. But the one thing I wonder is when I completely remove only the CSS, the radio button functions just fine and the ratings do submit per form.

Comment: Could you show us a bit more of your code - the form especially - and pass your site through a validator to see any problems e.g. with the repeated ids.

Comment: I edited the HTML and added the whole form

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises from the fact that you have several forms/groups of stars that have the same ids.

When you hover over a star then its succeeding siblings change to gold because of this CSS property:

```
.stars input:checked > label:hover,
.stars input:checked > label:hover ~ label{
  color: gold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px goldenrod;
}
```

So that's OK so far. But when you click on a star (ie the associated radio button is checked) this kind of CSS is invoked:

```
.stars #five:checked ~ .result:before{
  content: "I love it ";
}
.stars #four:checked ~ .result:before{
  content: "I like it ";
}
.stars #three:checked ~ .result:before{
  content: "It's good ";
}
.stars #two:checked ~ .result:before{
  content: "I don't like it ";
}
.stars #one:checked ~ .result:before{
  content: "I hate it ";
}
```

Notice that this uses amongst other things an id to determine which pseudo element is to have content. The system will find the first one, which is what we see, the right text is shown but in the wrong place - with the first set of stars every time.

You need to alter your code so that in the python loop a distinguishing feature (e.g. perhaps a counter which is incremented each time it goes through the look) is added to the ids so they are unique.

I recommend putting your site through a code validator as problems like this will be highlighted.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But won't the CSS get affected if I change the IDs of the radio?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to change that too.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking a lot about this. I think I got the id part but I'm not sure with the CSS.  I can't find any ways to modify the CSS id in the style block...